# Reshaping Dataframe without ID variable

Tags: python, pandas, reshape

I have a pandas dataframe that looks like this:

**var  |   info** 
id  |   1 
author  |   A 
title   |   B 
id  |   2 
author  |   C 
title   |   D

How can I  make it into wide format?

**id   |   author  |   title** 
1   |   A   |   B 
2   |   C   |   D

I don't have any id variables but each group of 3 observations should constitute a unique row.  Is there some way I can generate a unique id number for every 3 observations in the original dataframe?  Then I can reshape it easily.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the function [`repeat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.repeat.html) on Series to duplicate the `id` values in groups of three rows, and then use [`pivot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reshaping.html) to reshape the DataFrame:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'var': ['id', 'author', 'title', 'id', 'author', 'title'],
                   'info': [1, 'A', 'B', 2, 'C', 'D']})
df['id'] = df['info'].ix[::3].repeat(3).values
df_reshaped = df.pivot(index='id', columns='var', values='info')
# Discard the redundant 'id' column
df_reshaped = df_reshaped[['author', 'title']]
print df_reshaped
```

Output:

```
var author title
id              
1        A     B
2        C     D
```

Comment: Thanks so much!  This worked great.  Just one note, is there any way you can remove that second row that begins with "id" but has blank cells in the rest of the row?

Comment: It's actually just the name of the index. If you wish, you can remove it using `df_reshaped.index.name = None`. Same goes for `var`, which is the name of the columns.